# "An autonomous being" vs "autonomous being"? When to place an indefinite article?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article, being

He treats her as property rather than **an** autonomous being.

or

He treats her as property rather than autonomous being.

Which of the above sentences is correct and why?

Comment: *Property* is a mass (non-count) noun and does not take an article. *Autonomous being* is a countable noun and should have an article. In this case, a generic reference to such a thing requires the indefinite article.

Comment: I would further say that, stylistically and for clarity, the *as* should be repeated: *he treats her as property rather than  **as an** autonomous being.*